# Ruby on Rails Mac OSX 10.9 (Can't edit .rb files)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

this might be a very simple question but I have recently started using Ruby on Rails on my Mac that has Mavericks. I installed everything and started to build my website, now its time for me to open some .rb files and edit them but they are all read-only and I have no clue how to change the permissions, I'm using Sublime Text to try and edit these files, how do I change their permissions so I can make edits to them? (Every file is read-only including database.yml which I need to edit).

Thanks.

Comment: Did you run the `rails new <appname>` with some sort of elevated permissions like `sudo`? Did you create the app under a different login?

Comment: Look up "chmod". You might want to get familiar with the command line.

Answer (score 0):

How were they created?  Do the files show you as their owner? You can right click on the files/directory in finder, choose 'Get Info' and expand the 'Sharing and Permissions'.  You can also change permissions from here (to Read/Write, if they are Read Only).  If you want to do it recursively for your web app directory, you'll need to click the little padlock and then choose 'apply to enclosed items' from the cog/gear drop down menu.

Alternatively, you can recursively change permissions for the directories and files using the terminal and the 'chmod' command.  If the files are owned by you, going to the top directory of your web app and doing `chmod -R u+w *` should do the trick.

See more about traditional unix-style file permissions here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modes_%28Unix%29

Just experiment with one or two files if you're unsure.

Comment: Thank you, yeah I knew the solution was something easy. The trick is you have to click the padlock first and then enter your password then you can mess with permissions, that padlock icon is so small I didn't notice it.

Comment: My pleasure; I'm glad this was the solution.  It took me a while to notice/try the little padlock when I first looked at that section of the dialog too!